# Why does $\binom{n}{k} = 0$, if $k > n$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have came across this in a textbook that I am currently studying, but I don't understand how I should proof this.

A short explanation or proof would be nice.

Comment: Standard convention.  There are $0$ ways to choose $k$ objects out of $n$ if $k>n$.

Comment: Related [Does Combinatorial where r is greater than n a valid operation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{j+1}\tag1
$$
if $k\gt n\ge0$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the product contains a factor of $0$.

---

In the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem), $(1)$ is the definition of the binomial coefficients (with the convention that when $k=0$, $(1)$ is an [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), and therefore, $1$). They are only defined for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for $k\lt0$, $\binom{n}{k}=0$.

However, if $n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\binom{n}{k}\ne0$ for any integer $k\ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

For example expand the binomial
$$
(1+x)^n
$$
and the coefficient of $x^k$ is $\binom{n}{k}$ for all $k$.  [This is why it is called a **binomial coefficient**.]  Of course (when $n$ is a positive integer), this coefficient is $0$ for $k > n$.